# How to get a view of all products that are not in a pricelist?

Tags: reporting, list-view

How to get a view of all products that are not in a pricelist?

I've tried to do that with a report, but there's only a report for products that dó have a pricelist, while I want to see which products do nót have a pricelist.

I could go in and program something, but I'd rather stick to standard Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Standard SFDC reports won't help here so you can go into Data Loader, Developer Console or SFDC Workbench and execute the following SOQL

```
Select id, productcode from product2 
 where id not IN (select product2Id 
                   from pricebookentry 
                   where pricebook2.name = 'somePBName')  
 order by productCode
```

One way to find Product2s not on any pricebook would be:

```
Select id, productcode from product2 
  where id not IN (select product2Id 
                    from pricebookentry 
                    where pricebook2.isStandard = true)  
  order by productCode
```

as in order for a Product2 to be on a custom pricebook, it must first be on the standard pricebook